# Ruby Selenium Chrome location_once_scrolled_into_view not scrolling, unable to use elements not in view

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am attempting to click a button at the bottom of the page, which is out of view without scrolling down.  When I search for it to see if its displayed, the test passes.  But when i attempt to click it, I get the error:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timed out after 15 seconds (no such element: Unable to locateelement: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="page-top"]/div[1]/h2"}`

I have been told by others, and the more I play with it, I also believe that it is true that it can not click things out of view, which makes sense if Selenium is supposed to emulate someone browsing the website.

So in my attempts to find a way to scroll down, everything I find is telling me to use "element_to_find.location_once_scrolled_into_view".  A co-worker has never been able to get this to work, and neither have I. Maybe I am misunderstanding the actual purpose of it?  Or am I just using it incorrectly?  To clarify, this is Selenium in Ruby for Chrome.  Here is my code:

```
    assert @wait.until { @driver.find_element(xpath:'//*@id="cancel_form"]/button').displayed? } 
    # the above test passes

    sleep 1 # for good measure for the time being
    # line below is a link at bottom of page to bring cancel button into view
    terms_of_service_link = @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="terms_of_service_link"]') 

    tos_link = terms_of_service_link.displayed?
    assert_equal(true, tos_link) # this test passes as well.

    terms_of_service_link.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    cancel_account_button = @driver.find_element(id: 'cancel_form')

# this is the button i need to click.
    cancel_account_button.click()
```

and to make things a little more confusing for me, it is not the click() that is failing, or the scroll_into_view.  Whenever I attempt to use it, it always times out and the next test fails.  If the click was successful, it would run a test to verify it finds a piece of information that should always be on the next page.  That is where it fails:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timed out after 15 seconds (no such element: Unable to locateelement: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="page-top"]/div[1]/h2"}



     80:         @driver.find_element(id: 'cancel_form').click()
     81:         # sleep 1
  => 82:         assert @wait.until { @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="page-top"]/div[1]/h2').text.include? "We will be in touch shortly." }
```

I am not running this in headless mode so I can watch it work.  It navigates to the correct page, runs all the tests correctly up to the point where it has to find something located off screen.  Then it times out.  It seems to think its scrolling into view and clicking but it is not.

I can verify that it is the item not being in view causing it to fail because, if in one of my tests that involve send_keys on the same page, I add some send_key(:tab, :tab), it successfully tabs to the bottom of the page, then successfully clicks submit.  I would prefer not use tabs as the number of things potentially tabbed to could change at a point in time, whereas the id will likely always stay the same.

Any help with location_once_scrolled_into_view is greatly appreciated.  Or any other options would be welcome.

Comment: When you are clicking an element, selenium automatically bring that into the focus, If you want to check that, Just automate this stackoverflow page and try to click some element which is in the bottom, it would automatically scrolled up before it clicks. If something is hiding an element selenium would throw element not clickable error, but not when element is in bottom of page.

Comment: That is what I always assumed.  I had never even thought about it.  But I then realized I was always working with non-scrolling sites.  In my code, I tabbed to a link beyond what I needed to click, and then the click worked.  I tried many many different ways but if it was not visible, it wouldn't click it. I thought it odd, it's searching for ID, why would visibility matter?  I even left tabs out and manually scrolled when page loaded, successful click.  I didn't scroll, fail.  It makes no sense to me either, but I could record and show you.  Its basic html, nothing hidden or disabled.

Comment: Either way, do you know anything about location_once_scrolled_into_view?  Everything I read said that is supposed to scroll to identified element.  Neither I nor my coworker were able to get it to work.  Like, @driver.find_element (id: 'button_to_submit').location _once_scrolled_into_view.  That should literally scroll to the item, correct?  Or am I misinterpreting it's purpose, or perhaps it's behavior?  Maybe I am writing it wrong?  Anything at all besides:tab, :tab, :tab

Comment: I understand your problem, when the element is at the bottom of the page, selenium doesn't consider that element as invisible, it's visible for selenium. Invisible is something element exist but not visible that means you can't even manually click that element. To you give an example, Run this code for this same page `require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022080/ruby-selenium-chrome-location-once-scrolled-into-view-not-scrolling-unable-to-u'
driver.find_element(link_text: 'privacy policy').click
`

Comment: When you are ready to choose to go for selenium ruby binding, you can prefer to use WATIR which is a nice wrapper for selenium-ruby binding. Timings and related stuffs are maintained very neatly, It doesn't wait for an element using native driver implicit wait, it has its own clock.